# Show that two matrices are similar when matrix is not diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, similar-matrices

I have two matrices:

$$
  A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & -1 \\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\\ 1 & 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix}, B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 2 & 1 \\\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}
$$

To show that the two matrices are similar, I first found the eigenvalues of matrix A

$$
    \begin{align*}
        A & = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & -1 \\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\\ 1 & 0 & 3 \end{bmatrix} \\\
        |A - λE| & = λ^3 - 5λ^2 + (3+4-1)λ-(3+1) \\\ 
        & = λ^3-5λ^2+8λ-4 \\\
        & = (λ-1)(λ-2)^2 = 0 \\\
        |B - μ E| & = (μ-1)(μ-2)^2 = 0  
    \end{align*}
$$

Their eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are the same, therefore the sufficient condition of similarity of the matrix is established. Also, I have tried multiple times writing the matrix with the form $B = P^{-1}AP$. Yet, interestingly, I still failed to get the form just as matrix $B$.

The procedure that I took on matrix A is:

$$
    \begin{align*}
        & T_A(1) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 & -1 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\\ 1 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\\ y \\\ z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\\ 0 \\\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \\\
        & u_1 = \begin{bmatrix} -4 \\\ 1 \\\ 2 \end{bmatrix}
        \\\
        & T_A(2) = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 2 & -1 \\\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\\ y \\\ z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\\ 0 \\\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \\\
        & u_2 = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\\ 0 \\\ 1 \end{bmatrix},
        u_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 1  \\\ 2 \\\ 1 \end{bmatrix} 
    \end{align*}
$$

The $u_3$ is actually the cross product of $u_1, u_2$. The eigenvalue $2$ has an algebraic multiplicity of 2, yet its eigenvector is only $1$, this tells me that the matrix A is not diagonalizable. What did I mess up here?

Comment: $B$ is called the Jordan reduction of $A$. In fact to find $P$ just solve find the eigenvectors that verifiy $Au_1=u_1$,  $Au_2=2u_2+u_3$, $Au_3=2u_3$. If $A$ were diagonalisable you would solve only $Au_i=\lambda_iu_i$ equations, but here the second equation is just slightly modified.

Comment: You might find this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2433644/how-do-i-find-jordan-basis useful.

Comment: the other direction, good when the matrix entries are all integers and the eigenvalues are integers. Let the columns of $P$   be column vectors $p_1, p_2, p_3.$   Take $p_1$  with $(A-I) p_1 = 0,$  the genuine eigenvector. Since there are not enough 2-eigenvetors, jump to $p_3$  that satisfies both $(A-2I)^2 p_3 = 0, $  but $(A-2I) p_3 \neq  0, $  Finally define the middle column $p_2$  as $p_2 = (A-2I) p3.$   Make the matrix $P,$  find its inverse $P^{-1},$   finally calculate $J = P^{-1} A P$   I took $p_3 = (0,0,1)^T   ,$  worked well

Comment: @zwim Thank you, I have figured out this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the OP and comments suggested, the matrix can be found,

$$
    \begin{align*}
        & A[p_1,p_2,p_3] = [p_1,p_2,p_3]B \\\
        & A[p_1,p_2,p_3] = [p_1,2p_2,p_2+2p_3] \\\
    \end{align*}
$$

$$
    \begin{align*}
        \begin{cases} Ap_1 = p_1 \\\ Ap_2 = 2p_2 \\\ Ap_3 = p_2+2p_3\end{cases}
    \end{align*}
$$

$$
    \begin{align*}
        & (A-E)p_1 = 0 \\\
        & (A-E)p_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 & -1 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\\ 1 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \\\
        & p_1 = \begin{bmatrix} -4 \\\ 1 \\\ 2 \end{bmatrix}
    \end{align*}
$$

$$
    \begin{align*}
        & (A-2E)p_2 = 0 \\\
        & (A-2E)p_2 = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 2 & -1 \\\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \\\
        & p_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\\ 0 \\\ -1 \end{bmatrix}
    \end{align*}
$$

$$
    \begin{align*}
        & (A-2E)p_3 = p_2 \\\
        & (A-2E)p_3 = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 2 & -1 \\\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\\ 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\\ 0 \\\ -1 \end{bmatrix} \\\
        & p_3 = \begin{bmatrix} -1/2 \\\ 0 \\\ -1/2 \end{bmatrix}
    \end{align*}
$$

$$
    \begin{align*}
        B = P^{-1}AP =  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 2 & 1 \\\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}
    \end{align*}
$$

What I noticed is that the vectors should not be scaled in this case, especially the third column.